# Rails: Restricting pure javascript in the asset pipeline to specific views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amcharts

I'm trying to get my AMChart pure javascript out of my views and into the .js file in assets/javascripts/ for my controller, as Rails likes it.

I have two separate charts on two separate views, each with different configurations and data sources.

My problem is that when visiting one view I get a javascript error saying the variable that contains the chart data *for the other view* 'is not defined' - all javascript below this error is then aborted.

The AMChart javascript is just pure javascript (no jquery), and looks like this in my controller's .js file for the two charts:

```
/// Radar Chart for First View

  var chart;

  AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // RADAR CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmRadarChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData_radar1;  // <- data variable
    chart.categoryField = "criteria";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    chart.startEffect = ">";
    chart.sequencedAnimation = true;

    // VALUE AXIS
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.gridType = "circles";
    valueAxis.fillAlpha = 0.02;
    valueAxis.fillColor = "#000000"
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.1;
    valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    valueAxis.fontWeight = "bold"
    valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    valueAxis.maximum = 10;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.lineColor = "#98cdff"
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.4;
    graph.bullet = "round"
    graph.valueField = "score"
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]/10"
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // Balloon Settings
    var balloon = chart.balloon;
    balloon.adjustBorderColor = true;
    balloon.color = "#000000";
    balloon.cornerRadius = 5;
    balloon.fillColor = "#000000";
    balloon.fillAlpha = 0.7
    balloon.color = "#FFFFFF"

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
  });



/// Radar Chart for Second View

  var chart;

  // Draw AM Radar Chart
  AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // RADAR CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmRadarChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData_radar2;  // <- data variable
    chart.categoryField = "criteria";
    chart.startDuration = 0.3;
    chart.startEffect = ">";
    chart.sequencedAnimation = true;

    // GRAPH - FIRST 5
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "First 5";
    graph.lineColor = "#bdd523"
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.2;
    graph.bullet = "round"
    graph.valueField = "first5"
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]/10"
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // GRAPH - LAST 5
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "Last 5";
    graph.lineColor = "#98cdff"
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.2;
    graph.bullet = "round"
    graph.valueField = "last5"
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]/10"
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // VALUE AXIS
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.gridType = "circles";
    valueAxis.fillAlpha = 0.02;
    valueAxis.fillColor = "#000000"
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.1;
    valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    valueAxis.fontWeight = "bold"
    valueAxis.minimum = 0;
    valueAxis.maximum = 10;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // Balloon Settings
    var balloon = chart.balloon;
    balloon.adjustBorderColor = true;
    balloon.color = "#000000";
    balloon.cornerRadius = 5;
    balloon.fillColor = "#000000";
    balloon.fillAlpha = 0.7
    balloon.color = "#FFFFFF"

    // Legend Settings
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.position = "bottom";
    legend.align = "center";
    legend.markerType = "square";
    legend.rollOverGraphAlpha = 0;
    legend.horizontalGap = 5;
    legend.valueWidth = 5;
    legend.switchable = false;
    chart.addLegend(legend);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chart_radar");
  });
```

(For lack of a better method of getting data from my model into the js method I define 'chartData_radar1' or 'chartData_radar2' (called e.g. in line 7 above) in the view, e.g.)

```
:javascript
  var chartData_radar1 = #{Case.chart_analysis_radar(current_user)};
```

I'm not so much looking for a hack/workaround to get this to work, but more to know what is the Rails way to handle pure javascript like this in the asset pipeline? Is there a nice way to only load the javascript for one radar depending on the view, without having to put it in the view itself? I know if you use Jquery selector's you can selectively load parts of javascript, can I e.g. package this all up in jquery selectors somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Great question. I have also struggled getting amcharts to work when placed in a separate .js file.  To date, I have just kept it in the views as a workaround. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Thanks for the vote - glad to hear someone else is in the same position. Surely there must be a good way to do this in rails without putting the js in the views!

Comment: diasks2 - seems this question hasn't grabbed anyone.  I've been thinking that my problem here is primarily just a result of my unconventional method of getting data from rails to the javascript, defining the variable in the view like that.  Someone once recommended to me that the correct way to do this would be to use Ajax i.e. jquery $.get ... If this were done for all of the variables for AmCharts, then I wouldn't get these abortive 'undefined errors'...

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is pretty old, I'll try answering - might help someone.

Essentially what you want to do is sending your data from Rails view or controller to Javascript through a global variable:

```
:javascript
    window.chartData = #{JSON.stringify(@your_data)};
```

Then in any of your JS files in `assets/javascripts/` you can access this variable. However, make sure you are accessing it after the page has been loaded (So use jQuery's `$( document ).ready( function() { ... } )` or `window.onload = ...` if you are not using jQuery):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    ...
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmRadarChart();
    chart.dataProvider = window.chartData;
    ...
});
```

or

```
window.onload = function () {
    ...
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmRadarChart();
    chart.dataProvider = window.chartData;
    ...
};
```

You can also take this one step further. You can add something like this directly to your layout:

```
:javascript
    window.config = #{JSON.stringify(@js_config || {})};
```

And then in any of your controller methods all you need to do is:

```
@js_config[:chart_data] = some_chart_data
```

And now you can access this in any of your javascripts:

```
console.log(window.config.chart_data)
```

In this case, whether you need to wait for the page to load depends on whether you define your config variable in your head or body.